# ERROR: La anotación @RequestMapping no está permitida en las interfaces @FeignClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de microservicio en Spring y cuando voy a hacer uso del FeingClients, tengo un error y no estoy seguro a que se debe.

El error en específico es este:

```
2022-04-27 13:06:19.112 ERROR 16496 --- [           main] o.s.c.o.support.SpringMvcContract        : Cannot process class: com.practica2.userservice.feignclients.CarFeignClient. @RequestMapping annotation is not allowed on @FeignClient interfaces.
```

El problema, según veo, viene por esta parte del código:

```
 package com.practica2.userservice.feignclients;

    import com.practica2.userservice.model.Car;
    
    import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
    
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    
    @FeignClient(name = "car-service", url = "http//localhost:8002")
    
    @RequestMapping("/car")
    
    public interface CarFeignClient {

    @PostMapping()
    Car save(@RequestBody Car car);
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto el Application, me sale esto en la consola, luego se detiene, es decir que deja de correr.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Puedes declarar la anotación concreta con su respectivo verbo dentro de la interfaz, por ejemplo:
`@GetMapping(value = "/car")`

Ten en cuenta que no debes hacerlo a nivel de clase/interfaz si no a nivel de **método**.

Para tu caso puedes colocar el recurso directo en la url (`@FeignClient(name = "car-service", url = "http//localhost:8002/car"`) o hacer lo siguiente:

1. Define un bean que retorne un Feign.Builder:

   @Bean
   public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
   return Feign.builder()
   .target(CarFeignClient.class, "http://localhost:8082/car");
   }
2. Ahora tu interfaz se debe implementar así:

   public interface CarFeignClient {
   @PostMapping
   Car save(@RequestBody Car car);
   }

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/341022)

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/341027)

Comment: @L.Ronquillo la respuesta fue modificada con la respuesta y la solución